# azurerm_virtual_machine_extension creation procedure takes forever without stop in Azure Gov environment

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to install the OMS agent on linux machine, but it takes forever for the extension creation without stop

`vm.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "workspace"
  location            = "${var.azure_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.parent_rg.name}"
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 180
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "server" {
  name                  = "vm"
  vm_size               = "${var.jenkins_vm_size}"
  location              = "${var.azure_location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"]
  ...
  }

  tags = "${local.vm_tags}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "oms_mma" {
  name                       = "OMSExtension"
  location                   = "${var.azure_location}"
  resource_group_name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  virtual_machine_name       = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.server.name}"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                       = "OmsAgentForLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "1.7"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.workspace_id}"
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

The Terraform creation procedure continue running without stop:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.oms_mma: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
.
.
.
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.oms_mma: Still creating... [20m0s elapsed]
```

As I read in the MS doc, it says for Azure Gov env, I should add `-d` parameter which means `domain` for the command, such as:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/master/installer/scripts/onboard_agent.sh && sh onboard_agent.sh -w <YOUR WORKSPACE ID> -s <YOUR WORKSPACE PRIMARY KEY> -d opinsights.azure.us`

But I cannot find an example for the terraform script of the domain parameter. Does anyone has experience about this?

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4608

Comment: This is for windows through but might help ,The OMS Agent for Azure Government – A Cheat Sheet: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicole_welch/2017/05/the-oms-agent-for-azure-government-a-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @AnassKartit it is posted by me also... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would contact hashicorp support or create a github ticket in your case